# About Legendre transform in Evan's PDE: Show that (i) $v\in \partial H(p)$ iff (ii) $p\in \partial H^*(v)$ iff (iii) $v\cdot p=H(p)+H^*(v)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

> Let $H: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. We say $v\in \partial H(p)$ if 
>   $$H(r)\geq H(p)+v\cdot(r-p)$$
>   for all $r\in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Prove that (i) $v\in \partial H(p)$ iff (ii) $p\in \partial H^*(v)$ iff (iii) $v\cdot p=H(p)+H^*(v)$.

Here $H^*(v):=\sup_{p}\{v\cdot p-H(p)\}$

---

My idea:

I just try to prove that (i) $\to$ (ii) $\to $ (iii) $\to $ (i) .

But For (i) $\to$ (ii), we know $$H(r)\geq H(p)+v\cdot(r-p)$$. How to show that 
$$H^*(r)\geq H^*(p)+v\cdot(r-p)?$$

I am stuck in 
$$rp-H(p)\geq vr-H(r)+p(r-v)$$
So $\sup[rp-H(p)]\geq \sup[vr-H(r)+p(r-v)]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know
$$H(r)\geq H(p)+v\cdot(r-p) \quad \forall r \in \mathbb{R}$$
so
$$v\cdot p - H(p) \geq v\cdot r - H(r) \quad \forall r \in \mathbb{R}$$
so $$v\cdot p - H(p) \geq \sup_r \{ v\cdot r - H(r)\} = H^*(v)$$
Since $v\cdot p - H(p) \leq \sup_p \{ v\cdot p - H(p) \}=H^*(v)$, we have $v\cdot p - H(p) = H^*(v)$.
Showing (ii) is now trivial: the right hand side simplifies to $pr-H(p)$, and taking the supremum over $p$ gives the desired result.